# "ls" command output

Tags: shell, unix, ls

I'm running `ls -l` which brings the following output:

> `-rw-r----- 1 webadm webgrp    168 Jul 19 16:00 SYNCHRO_20120719_1600.csv`

Is there a way to have just get the last two fields? i.e:

> `16:00 SYNCHRO_20120719_1600.csv`

Comment: If we're going to mark this one off-topic, shouldn't it at least be migrated to somewhere appropriate (ie. superuser)?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 ls -l | awk '{print $(NF-1), " ", $NF}'
```

It will display the next-to-last and last fields on the line, which is the time and the name of the directory entry and is *not dependent* on a specific number for a field.

May create problems with names that contains blanks however.

See [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) regarding use of `'ls'` for processing, provided by @CharlesDuffy which somewhat undermines the approach above :-) .. so the quick solution presented ought to be viewed in that context.

Comment: Not just names with blank spaces -- how `ls` munges names in general (including ones with other forms of non-printable characters) isn't well-defined across implementations. Much better to use shell globbing to get the names, and something else (which _could_ be ls) to read their times. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the feedback, useful information and so noted. I agree, this is an awkward (and quite possibly "iffy") solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
ls -l | awk '{print $8" "$9}'
```

Comment: This won't work as-is with filenames with spaces.

Comment: For my linux account I had to use fields $7 and $8

Comment: This not at all meant to be a general solution. It's just the simplest command I could find that is able to handle the file format as shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

On a system with GNU date:

```
for f in *; do
    printf '%s %s\n' "$(date +%H:%M -r "$f")" "$f"
done
```

This will work correctly with filenames with spaces -- or even filenames with newlines, though it won't be possible to distinguish between filename-embedded newlines and record-separated ones. (Use null delimiters if this is important).